# function to return pyplot object but not plot it unless explicitly specified

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a function that would return a `pyplot` object but will not plot it out unless explicitly specified.

Following is a example function similar to what I'm trying to create.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_it_now():
    A = np.linspace(0,10,10)
    B = np.exp(A)
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(A, label='linear sequence')
    plt.plot(B, label='exponential sequence')
    plt.xlabel('x-axis')
    plt.ylabel('y-axis')
    plt.legend(loc='best')

myplot = plot_it_now()
```

the problem is the moment I call this function into a variable it also plots it out. While that's the usual behaviour, I want to persist the pyplot object into a variable and it should plot it only when i call it. Something like this,

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
myplot = plot_it_now()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plot_it_now()` doesn't return any value so you have `myplot = None`. If you don't what to see plot then don't run `plot_it_now()`. `plot()` creates objects directly on  figure and axis - and it may create many separated objects (if you plot dots or bars).

Comment: maybe you need `set_visible` [python - How to toggle visibility of matplotlib figures? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463479/how-to-toggle-visibility-of-matplotlib-figures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib` has an [interactive mode](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html).

To check its state :

```
import matplotlib as mpl

print(mpl.is_interactive())
# True = on
# False = off
```

---

**IDE** (Spyder in my case) **or python console**

Disable interactive mode before the matplotlib commands:

```
plt.ioff()
```

Then you need an explicite `plt.show()` to display the plot.

---

**Jupyter notebook**

Heads-up, I had to install `ipympl` first to call `%matplotlib widget` (see the switch states below):

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipympl
pip install ipympl
```

See [ipympl installing](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/installing.html) for more options.

**Switch off:**

```
%matplotlib widget
plt.ioff()

# matplotlib commands
```

Note: Then 'just' a `plt.show()` isn't enough to display the plot, see next step.

**Switch on:**

```
%matplotlib inline
# plt.ion()  # actually not required since 'inline' will switch in on automatically

# matplotlib commands 
#   in your case the myplot = plot_it_now()
#     a plt.show() like for the console isn't enough
```

---

Kudos to [towardsdatascience How to produce Interactive Matplotlib Plots in Jupyter Environment](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-produce-interactive-matplotlib-plots-in-jupyter-environment-1e4329d71651) and [SO Matplotlib can't suppress figure window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970002/matplotlib-cant-suppress-figure-window) with its answers.
Since the latter one was about python 2.7 from the question I think an update is feasible.

Comment: wow! I never knew of this feature of `matplotlib`. I learned something new today, thanks!